# Seaborn Heatmap Colorbar Label as Percentage

Tags: python-3.x, heatmap, seaborn

Given this heat map:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
```

How would I go about making the color bar values display in percent format?
Also, what if I just wanted to show the first and last values on the color bar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

iterating on the solution of @mwaskom, without creating the colorbar yourself:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
data = np.random.rand(8, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(data, vmin=0, vmax=1)
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.set_ticks([0, .2, .75, 1])
cbar.set_ticklabels(['low', '20%', '75%', '100%'])
```

[image: custom seaborn heatmap color bar labels]

Comment: do you know how i can do the same for the ticks i.e. 0-7 and 0-11

Comment: does anyone know why I can't pass `xticklabels` as argument of `cbar_kws`? Or am I passing the argument somehow wrong? For setting the `ticks` it is working fine.

Answer (score 22):

Well, I had a similar problem and figured out how to [properly set a formatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter). Your example would become something like:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
uniform_data = 100 * uniform_data

sns.heatmap(uniform_data,
            cbar_kws={'format': '%.0f%%'})
```

So, what you have to do is to pass an *old-style string formatter* to add percentages to colorbar labels. Not exactly what I would name self-evident, but works...

To show only the first and last, then you add `vmax`, `vmin` and an extra parameter to `cbar_kws`:

```
sns.heatmap(uniform_data,
            cbar_kws={'format': '%.0f%%', 'ticks': [0, 100]},
            vmax=100,
            vmin=0)
```

Answer (score 10):

You should get the colour bar object and then get the relevant axis object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax, cbar_kws={'label': 'My Label'})
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1, 0))
```

Comment: This solution works great if the first and last values of the colorbar are unknown. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to be able to access the colorbar object. It might be buried in the figure object somewhere, but I couldn't find it, so the easy thing to do is just to make it yourself:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, cbar=False, vmin=0, vmax=1)
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(ax.collections[0])
cbar.set_ticks([0, 1])
cbar.set_ticklabels(["0%", "100%"])
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks. Do you know where I can find a list of possible annot_kws and cbar_kws?

Comment: refer to [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar) documentation...