# Seaborn, change font size of the colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I wanted to change the font size for a heatmap colorbar.

The following is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange
x = arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, sep=20, as_cmap=True)
ax = sns.heatmap(x, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

I was able to change the tick labels with `plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=20)`. However, the colorbar font size does not change. 
Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the font scale with the `seaborn.set()` method setting the `font_scale` param to the scale you want, see more in seaborn [documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.set.html#seaborn.set).

For example, your plot with scale 3:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange
# here set the scale by 3
sns.set(font_scale=3)
x = arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, sep=20, as_cmap=True)
ax = sns.heatmap(x, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot with big font scale]

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, since you are changing the fontsizes for all of the labels ...

Comment: Agreed but I am not sure how or even if it is possible to change the scale of just one label. Sorry if that does not solve your problem...

Answer (score 35):

You can use [matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) with labelsize.

For example, your plot with labelsize 20:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange
x = arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, sep=20, as_cmap=True)
ax = sns.heatmap(x, cmap=cmap)
# use matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar object
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
# here set the labelsize by 20
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I refered to the following answer:
 - [Using matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820239/seaborn-heatmap-colorbar-label-as-percentage)
 - [Setting parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184696/change-fontsize-of-colorbars-in-matplotlib)

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer since it shows how to change the colorbar label size independently from the other label sizes, as opposed to Filipe Amaral's answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you set the following, it will increase all text in the graph by a factor of two. However, if you immediately set the tick_params to lower right after, you will be left with just the font size of the colorbar increased.

```
sns.set(font_scale=2)

sns.heatmap(df, vmin=0, vmax=1, center=0.5)

heatmap.tick_params(labelsize=15)

sns.set(font_scale=1)
```

Don't forget to set the font_scale back :)