# Python: how to change size and text label of colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am doing a plot like this:

```
fig, ax =  plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.style.use("dark_background")
comdis3.plot(column='diff',  ax=ax, cmap='RdBu', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='RdBu', norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)
```

[image]

How can I modify the size and the text of the colorbar ticks. For instance I would like `-10%` instead of `-10` and increase the fontsize.

Comment: You have asked two questions in one question. For the percentage thing, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820239/seaborn-heatmap-colorbar-label-as-percentage)

Comment: @Sheldore I tried but I get this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_ticks'`

Comment: Include what you tried and what didnt work in your question for others to know